# Issue with Volume Mounting after Server Restart

Tags: linux, raid, mount, zpool, ecryptfs

Originally  on bkp-01 instance. The server and disk have manually been set to a different availability zone. The disk are running zfs for backups/snapshots. It's an old server with a **manual Raid** system.

Now if we check :

```
root@bkp-01:~# cat /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.

#

# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a

# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices

# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

#

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

UUID=g5e223df-f541-4e4c-aa8d-e4529fa28424 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0

UUID=98a5392a-3fbc-67aa-bd15-b3e6f125c27a none swap sw 0 0

/storage/backups/revitalis /storage/mount-revitalis ecryptfs ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,key=passphrase:passfile=/root/tmp-pass-revitalis.txt,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,no_sig_cache,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,noauto 0 0

/storage/backups/cromwell /storage/mount-cromwell ecryptfs ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,key=passphrase:passfile=/root/tmp-pass-cromwell.txt,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,no_sig_cache,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,noauto 0 0

/storage/backups/cilon /storage/mount-cilon ecryptfs ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,key=passphrase:passfile=/root/tmp-pass-cilon.txt,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,no_sig_cache,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,noauto 0 0

/storage/backups/glueckauf /storage/mount-glueckauf ecryptfs ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,key=passphrase:passfile=/root/tmp-pass-glueckauf.txt,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,no_sig_cache,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,noauto 0 0
```

And

```
root@bkp-01:~# ls -l /root/tmp-pass-revitalis.txt

-rw------- 1 root root 40 Sep  2  2020 /root/tmp-pass-revitalis.txt

root@bkp-01:~# ls -ld /storage/backups/revitalis

ls: cannot access /storage/backups/revitalis: No such file or directory

root@bkp-01:~# ls -ld /storage/mount-revitalis

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 14 10:51 /storage/mount-revitalis
```

root@bkp-01:~#
: **we had the below
A working setup for an older server (bkp-01) type should look like that:
Before the restart**

```
root@bkp-01:/# zpool status

 pool: storage

state: ONLINE

 scan: scrub repaired an in 701hSflm with 0 errors on Mon Jan 9 06:14:20 2023

config:

    NAME                STATE        READ   WRITE   CKSUM

    storage             ONLINE        0      0       0

      raidz1-0          ONLINE        0      0       0

       vdc              ONLINE        0      0       0

       vdb              ONLINE        0      0       0

      raidz1-1          ONLINE        0      0       0

       vde              ONLINE        0      0       0

       vdd              ONLINE        0      0       0

      raidz1-2          ONLINE        0      0       0

       vdf              ONLINE        0      0       0

       vdg              ONLINE        0      0       0
```

Now  if we check To check available disk space

After the server restat we have :

```
root@bkp-01:~#  zfs list

no datasets available

root@bkp-01:~# zpool status

no pools available
```

This backup error are showing on the logs as :

```
Backup [Test] /usr/bin/rsync -a "rsync://10.11.11.195/encrypted" "/storage/backups/Test/" failed with rc 11 rsync: mkdir "/storage/backups/Test" failed: No such file or directory (2) rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(674) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

**We tried :**

```
mount /storage/mount-revitalis

output 

/storage/backups/revitalis /storage/mount-revitalis ecryptfs ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,key=passphrase:passfile=/root/tmp-pass-revitalis.txt,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,no_sig_cache,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,noauto 0 0
passfile=/root/tmp-pass-revitalis.txt
```

And

```
root@bkp-01:~# mount /storage/mount-revitalis
Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=32
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=750ba1ab642008df
Error mounting eCryptfs: [-2] No such file or directory
Check your system logs; visit <http://ecryptfs.org/support.html>
```

Is this happen because of : Originally there was a ZFS pool "storage" with RAIDZ1 vdevs, After a reboot, the ZFS pool is missing entirely and This is causing backups to fail due to missing mount points?

Do Recreate the ZFS pool and Recreate the datasets  will help here ?

Any help would be higly appriocate!